# Can I give access to users from outside of the network via link which will need to be downloaded in limited time in linux FTP server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp, symbolic-link

I am new in Ubuntu Linux. Here is my task,

1. Set up an FTP server.
2. Add users to this FTP server and create new directories in their home directories.
3. Give access to users from outside of network via a link (I guess I need to use symbolic link for this issue).
4. When this link is generated, it should be downloaded in limited times like transferring files via WeTransfer.

So far, I learned how to do task 1 and 2, but I am not sure about task 3 and 4.

Please guide me and correct me if I did anything wrong. Thanks in advance. Stay safe and healthy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using nextcloud which is opensource and free to use.
It can allow you to share files/dirs with other users (ldap, AD, built-in or even guests), or provide a link to some resource with the option to limit it in time (link expiration).
Also, you can provide link to external users where they can upload only, download or full access

Also, Nextcloud is far more secure (works with SELINUX) - yet it's more compex as it has a REDIS cache server, database and a web server.

Keep in mind that FTP in active mode is far more difficult to setup, when the server is behind a firewall.

Comment: Thanks for your advice and comment.  It is helpful. However, I need to do these in  FTP Server.

Comment: Do you know external users's IP Address ? If yes, you can manipulate the FTP server's firewall to limit access based on time (some kind of link expiration).

Comment: No, I do not know that

Comment: Then your last way to manage external access will be via cron/atd job to remove that share after X time. FTP is quite limited for your needs and it's no surprise that owncloud and nextcloud (fork of owncloud) has come up as ideas.